# I want set a <lable> element align left,but it always in centre,don't why

Tags: html, forms

I was writing a login page with bootstrap.

The lable for checkbox is always in centre.

```
    <div class="container text-center" >
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col"></div>

        <div class="col">
          ....
          <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>

            ...

            <!-- 用户协议 -->
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-check ">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck" style="text-align: left;">勾选即表示同意《用户协议》</label>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>

                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  You must agree before submitting.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            ...

        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[login_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI1Il.png)

I try adding "text-align:left",or change the "display" to "inline".
But it does not help.

Unless I change the div class from 'col-12' to 'col-7'.

I don't know why,and how to set it.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by adding text-align in the parent div.

```html
<div class="form-check" style="text-align: left;">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">勾选即表示同意《用户协议》</label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        You must agree before submitting.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thinks,it works.

But why this text-align can't be add in label,inline style shold be more priority,doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="col"></div>

    <div class="col">
      ....
      <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>

        ...

        <!-- 用户协议 -->
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="form-check ">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck" style="text-align: left;">勾选即表示同意《用户协议》</label>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>

            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              You must agree before submitting.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        ...

    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).